# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' in pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, stanford-nlp, word2vec

Code

```
df=pd.read_csv('x.csv', encoding= 'unicode_escape')
```

utf-8 gave error

Traceback

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_9236/1406487559.py in <module>
      2                 #for review in train['Short_Description']:
      3 
----> 4 sentences = list(train['Cleaned_Description'].map(lambda x: re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]"," ", (x).decode('utf-8')).lower().split()))
      5 test_sentences = []  # Initialize an empty list of sentences
      6                          #for review in test['Short_Description']:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in map(self, arg, na_action)
   4159         dtype: object
   4160         """
-> 4161         new_values = super()._map_values(arg, na_action=na_action)
   4162         return self._constructor(new_values, index=self.index).__finalize__(
   4163             self, method="map"

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in _map_values(self, mapper, na_action)
    868 
    869         # mapper is a function
--> 870         new_values = map_f(values, mapper)
    871 
    872         return new_values

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

/tmp/ipykernel_9236/1406487559.py in <lambda>(x)
      2                 #for review in train['Short_Description']:
      3 
----> 4 sentences = list(train['Cleaned_Description'].map(lambda x: re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]"," ", (x).decode('utf-8')).lower().split()))
      5 test_sentences = []  # Initialize an empty list of sentences
      6                          #for review in test['Short_Description']:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: I tried to put the code from the title into a code block. But..., the code giving the error doesn't seem to be part of the read_csv. You've got an `x`, I don't know what it is. But apparantly its a string, and strings get _encoded_ (use `.encode`) not  _decoded_.

Comment: Make a [mcve]. Make a script and sample .csv that reproduces the error and paste it *exactly* here by editing the question.